# Having trouble creating my Neural Network inputs

Tags: machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, neural-network

I'm currently working on a neural network that should have N parameters in input. Each parameters can have M different values (discrete values), let's say {A,B,C,…,M}. It also has a discrete number of outputs.

How can I create my inputs from this situation? Should I have N×M inputs (having 0 or 1 as value), or should I think of a different approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either have `NxM` boolean inputs or have `N` inputs where each one is a float that goes from `0` to `1`. In the latter case the float values would be: `{A/M, B/M, C/M, ... 1}`. For example if you have 4 inputs each one with discrete values:  `{1,2,3,4}` then you can change the domain values to `{0.25 , 0.50 , 0.75 , 1.00}`.

Actually there are a lot of ways to encode your inputs, but I have found better results when my inputs lie in the domain `[0,1]` (as there are some ML functions that expect that).

Comment: When treating discrete values as different floats, does it create a "relation" between each value ? For example, A would be more like B than K.

Comment: Yes, it will. If that is not desired or poses problems then the `NxM` booleans are a better bet.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes it's important that all discrete values stays independant. I'll try the NxM approach. Thanks